# What could be causing the code to function correctly locally but only partially on the staging environment?

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi, apache-tika, staging

I am using tika and poi dependencies to detect file mime types and storing those files accordingly.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public final class FileTypeUtils {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileTypeUtils.class);
    
    private FileTypeUtils() {
    }

    public static String getFileType(File inputFile) throws Exception {

        final Tika tika = new Tika();
        try {
            return tika.detect(inputFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("*** getFileTypeViaTika2 - Error message: " + e.getMessage());
            LOGGER.error("*** getFileTypeViaTika2 - Error trace"+e);
            throw new Exception("File type unknown");
        }
        
    }
}
```

this is the method caller

```
    public void saveMediaFile(String url, WhatsAppMessageContentTypeValidation whatsAppMessageContentTypeValidation) {
        String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        try {
            File file = new File(Pl4WhatsAppConstants.mediaFilePath + fileName.replace(" ", "-"));
            if (url != null && url.contains("https")) {
                URL fileUrl = new URL(url.replace(" ", "-"));
                SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

                // set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
                sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        LOGGER.info("getAcceptedIssuers =============");
                        return null;
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        LOGGER.info("checkClientTrusted =============");
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        LOGGER.info("checkServerTrusted =============");
                    }
                } }, new SecureRandom());
                // Apache HttpClient version >4.2 should use BasicClientConnectionManager
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
                HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) fileUrl.openConnection();
                FileUtils.copyURLToFile(connection.getURL(), file, 30000, 30000);
            } else {
                URL fileUrl = new URL(url.replace(" ", "-"));
                FileUtils.copyURLToFile(fileUrl, file, 30000, 30000);
            }
            String contentTypeString = FileTypeUtils.getFileType(file);
            LOGGER.info("Content Mime type {}", contentTypeString);
            whatsAppMessageContentTypeValidation.setVendorMimeType(contentTypeString);
            whatsAppMessageContentTypeValidation.setFileName(fileName);
            whatsAppMessageContentTypeValidation.setMediaType(getMediaType(contentTypeString));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            whatsAppMessageContentTypeValidation
                    .setValidationError(Pl4WhatsAppRequestValidations.CANNOT_RETRIEVE_MEDIA_TO_SEND);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            whatsAppMessageContentTypeValidation
                    .setValidationError(Pl4WhatsAppRequestValidations.CANNOT_DETERMINE_MEDIA_TYPE);
        }
    }

    private Pl4WhatsAppMediaType getMediaType(String fileType) {
        if (fileType.contains("image")) {
            return Pl4WhatsAppMediaType.IMAGE;
        } else if (fileType.contains("video")) {
            return Pl4WhatsAppMediaType.VIDEO;
        } else {
            return Pl4WhatsAppMediaType.DOCUMENT;
        }
    }
```

these are my maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>1.28.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

locally, all the expected file types(doc,docx, ppt, pptx, pdf, jpg, mp3, mp4, txt..) are going through. but on the staging environment docx, pptx, xlsx are not going through.

on stage docx, pptx and xlsx are detected as "application/x-tika-ooxml" but locally they are detected as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, respectively.

I tried copying the jars from stage and ran them locally via cmd, and send the request via postman the problem was replicated. then I used the jars generated locally and I got the expected results (all the files going through).

So I would like to know about the causes of such behavor.

Comment: Why are you mixing Apache Tika jar versions? That is not supported! Use only 1.x or 2.x, not a mixture!

Comment: I tried doing that, but docx, pptx, xlsx were read as "application/x-tika-ooxml" and invalid mime types. I could be wrong though, is poi responsible for MS files or they work hand in hand with tika. if that is the case, I will try updating the poi version only and use the same version for tika core and parsers as you advised.

Comment: Each version of Apache Tika is built against a specific version of Apache POI. Just let Tika pull in the version of POI it wants

Comment: Thanks a lot; everything is functioning as expected now, in both environments.